# I am from Northern Ireland, but live in Scotland, and need to complete an advanced disclosure. Should I do this for both Countries?

Tags: united-kingdom, legal, ireland

Basically, I am from Northern Ireland, but recently (within the past month) moved to Scotland.

I went to University in Scotland close to ten years ago, I lived here for about three years.

I work for a startup handling sensitive financial data, so we have agreed that I should complete an advanced disclosure. I have no issue with this.

However, having not been in Scotland in nearly a decade, should I do this with the Scottish authorities as well, or is Northern Ireland enough?

*Edit:* Just to clarify, we are doing this to help with compliance, but haven't been given any specific instruction. It is my job to figure out what is necessary.

[Northern Ireland AccessNI](https://www.nidirect.gov.uk/information-and-services/accessni-criminal-record-checks/apply-accessni-check)

[Scotland](https://www.mygov.scot/disclosure-types/)

Comment: Would you mind explaining what is an advanced disclosure?, so other users get a better context of your situation.

Comment: @DarkCygnus Updated the question with relevant links

Comment: Doesn't your financial instruction already have some on whose job it is to handle this? Like you would have a "security" officer id you held Security clearances. Also where are you working NI or Scotland

Comment: @Neuromancer It's not actually required at this point, we've just decided to do it anyway. We are in the FCA Sandbox and are doing everything we can do exceed the requirements. I am trying to understand what the standard requirement would be in this situation.

Comment: Is no one else surprised that there isn't just a single entity that handles all of the UK (of GB and NI)?

Comment: @Shoover Nope, even Scotland and England have different procedures for requesting a check. I'm pretty sure if you have one though, it also covers the other countries, but best to ask the company to be sure

Comment: "*we are doing this to help with compliance, but haven't been given any specific instruction. It is my job to figure out what is necessary.*" Since it's safe to assume that you're not a compliance officer or legal expert given that you wouldn't be asking this question if you were, what a recipe for disaster that is. Are you sure you're not taking on legal responsibility here?

Answer (score 5):

> However, having not been in Scotland in nearly a decade, should I do this with the Scottish authorities as well, or is Northern Ireland enough?

The best way to be sure is to **ask the ones that are asking you for such disclosure. They can probably then tell you which one(s) they want.**

IANAL, but I think that it would make sense to **obtain such disclosure for the country/region you are working for** (Scotland in this case).

If you are not completely sure, and is up to you to determine which one(s) you have to chose (or if the ones that asked you such are unable to clarify what they want), then **consulting a lawyer** could give you a better (and safer) idea.

You could also well obtain the disclosure of **both countries** just in case, so you are prepared for any situation, and if it is not impossible to do.

Comment: Thanks, I think Both Countries is the way to go, was asking mainly to see if somebody who had been in a similar situation could advise on such.

Comment: @JMK glad I could help :). Anyways, you could still benefit from consulting a lawyer about this, just to be sure and cover your back from unexpected scenarios.

Answer (score 4):

### If only applying for [Basic Disclosure](https://www.mygov.scot/basic-disclosure/) (NI information [here](https://www.nidirect.gov.uk/articles/types-accessni-checks))

*A basic disclosure certificate shows any 'unspent' criminal convictions you may have in the UK*

As per the Scotland website, it's solely dependant on where you live:

> From 3 January 2018, if you live in England or Wales, you should apply
>   for your criminal record check from the Disclosure and Barring
>   Service.
>
> **If you live in Scotland, you should apply for your disclosure from
>   Disclosure Scotland.**

[Source](https://www.mygov.scot/organisations/disclosure-scotland/)

Also reading through the information, both checks will check your criminal record in the UK as a whole.

**NI:**

> When an employer requires criminal record information, they must keep
>   to rules about requesting criminal records and making recruitment
>   decisions based on records disclosed. **As AccessNI cannot search
>   criminal records outside the UK**, except for some EU countries,
>   employers should take other steps to check job applicants from abroad.

[Source](https://www.nidirect.gov.uk/articles/checking-job-applicants-employees-and-volunteers)

**Scotland:**

> A basic disclosure certificate shows any 'unspent' criminal
>   convictions you may have in the UK.

[Source](https://www.mygov.scot/basic-disclosure/)

So get the Scotland check, as it covers all of the UK and will show all criminal convictions. Getting both is just doing the same checks twice by a different entity.

---

### If applying for [Standard or enhanced disclosure](https://www.mygov.scot/convictions-higher-disclosures/) (NI information [here](https://www.nidirect.gov.uk/articles/types-accessni-checks))

*If you have a higher level disclosure, your certificate will show:*

- *all unspent convictions*
- *certain spent convictions that must always be disclosed*
- *other spent convictions as set out by law*

If you need a higher level disclosure than basic, your company must be registered with the controlling agency:

**NI:**

> Registered bodies are AccessNI approved organisations. **Only these
>   organisations are authorised to make applications for standard and
>   enhanced checks.**

[Source](https://www.nidirect.gov.uk/articles/general-information-accessni-employers)

**Scotland:**

> Standard and enhanced disclosures
>   involve higher level checks.
>
> They are for people doing certain types of work or looking to adopt
>   and are applied for **by your employer or a registered body representing
>   you.**

[Source](https://www.mygov.scot/disclosure-types/)

So going on the above information, it shouldn't be you getting the form, but your employee providing the form (Unless they only want the basic). They need to register with the Scottish body at this [link](https://www.mygov.scot/register-organisation-disclosure/), if the company resides in Scotland, or with the NI body at this [link](https://www.nidirect.gov.uk/services/apply-online-standard-check-through-registered-body).

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the Scottish version of CRB checks (basic checks against the legal records). In your case I would hire a lawyer/ specialist (on the companies dime) to produce a proper procedure and information for those going through the checks.

Comment: That costs money whilst asking the company what they want is free, Why would you hire a lawyer for a 5 second question when there are other resources to use? Seems overkill

Comment: @Draken because in the finance industry screwing up regulatory issues can lead to large fines and the OP possibly being blamed / fired and worse case banned for life from the industry